# Can't clear char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

My C application reads a file character by character and stores the char value in a char array. At a certain point, the char array needs to be cleared so another value can be entered. However, when I try to clear it, the chars still remain in the array.

This is how I reset the array:

```
void resetArray(){
    operand[0] = '\0';
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your array `operand` defined as?? How are you accessing it ?

Comment: @brokenfoot `char operand[4];`

Comment: I hope you know this: if your array contains "ABCDE\0", then the way you are resetting it, makes it "\0BCDE\0". What do you mean you can't clear it?? Post some more code and your expected and actual output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the first character as the null terminator will leave the rest of the array in memory intact. Printing the string will not print them, but they are still there.

You have to clear the remaining memory.

```
memset( array , 0 , sizeof( array ) ) ;
```

Comment: The above assumes that 'array' is actually an array and not a pointer, which is probably correct in your example but it something to bear in mind for dynamic allocation.

Comment: @user3303729 I never used the word pointer, so it doesn't assume anything.  :)

Comment: @hd1 *Arrays and pointers are the same thing in C. – hd1 3 mins ago* Can I quote you on that?

Comment: @everyone else They are not the same thing. http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html